# I'm trying to capture a string using regex. the following is a sample of the text file im trying to extract the data from

Tags: c#, regex

```
        sample data1:              value1                      sampledata2: value value 2                                
       sample data3:                                            data3       sampledata5:      
        sampledata4: value value  value2
sampledata6:                     sampledata7: value-value,value
```

I tried the following regex:

```
(*keywordsample* *\d+ *:[ ]{0,25})([\w\-\,\.] {0,2})+
```

I assumed that if there 25 whitespaces after the *keyword:*, then the value is null for that keyword.
values have 2 spaces at most. Ex:

```
value  value - valid
 valuevalue - valid 
value   value-invalid(3 whitespaces between values)
```

The following data has values:

- sample data1-value1
- sampledata2-value value 2
- sample data3-data3
- sampledata5-null
- sampledata4-value value  value2
- sampledata6-null
- sampledata7-value-value,value

However, i think the 25 spaces is not safe.
Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Not clear what you asking.

Comment: sorry forgot to edit the sample data i think its more readable now

Answer (score 0):

Will there ever be any other value than whitespace?
You can reverse the logic and check for anything, not whitespace. Use it in conjunction with the end of line specifier and the Multiline option and you should be good to go.

Something like:

```
keyword\s*([^\s]*)$
```

### Based on comments:

Okay nevermind my previous edit ;) I Finally got behind a computer and nailed it (probably needs some minor tweaks to fit your case exactly):

```
keyword:\s*([^\s:]+\s{0,2}[^\s:]*)\s[^s]+:
```

The lesson here is you should look for something that can be used as a delimiter. In this case, there is not much to work with, except the knowledge that there will be another keyword followed by a :

Again, for values at the end of a line use:

```
keyword:\s*([^\s:]+\s{0,2}[^\s:]*)$
```

Comment: i did not clearly understand your answer but what I'm trying to do is capture the words(with whitespaces 2 at most) after the keyword and colon without relying on specific number of whitespaces after colon. But if ever the value after the colon is words(with whitespaces 2 at most) but preceeded by colon or end of line, then the value for that keyword would be null

Comment: Your question was a bit unclear. It's be something more like this: keyword:\w*([^\w]*\w{0,2}[^\w]*)

Comment: Typing on my phone here. So check the syntax :)

Comment: I tried your syntax. For this sample
`Keyword1:                     Keyword2:`
if keyword1 is supplied, it matched `Keyword2:      Keyword2:` but it should be null.
It should work like this:
`Keyword1:             value1             Keyword2:`
if keyword1 is supplied, value1 will be matched
Ill try to post a screenshot later to make it clearer, i cant upload images in the office

Comment: Okay. I didn't realize the data would be on the same line. That makes it a bit harder. It would be easier if you post a few lines of data

Comment: Yes that is my problem. That is why i used whitespace{0,25} for now after the colon to check if value is null. It works with all the test data i have but I don't know if this is a guarantee though. I'll add sample data later

Comment: think i nailed it this time :) 
if you're on windows, try a little program called expresso. It's free an gives you some nice feedback on how your regex is built. It uses the .net flavour of regex, but should be fine for most use cases. you can find other tools like this online.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in regex but what I tried to do is to capture every words and spaces(2 at most between words) after the keyword colon. After that I check the match if it contains a colon, if it does, I'll consider it as null.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=keyword {0,1}: *)\b(\w+ {0,2})(?!( {0,2}\w)+:)\b`

finally discovered the answer thank you for the ideas

Comment: Good call in using \b 
Also, you can use ? instead of {0,1}
It means the same thing but it's a bit shorter to write